# Is this gcc/clang past-one pointer comparison behavior conforming or non-standard?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, clang

Even though the C Standard explicitly recognizes for the possibility that an address which points "just past" one object might by happenstance compare equal to one which points "to" another unrelated object, both gcc and clang seem to operate on the assumption that no pointer that is observed to point just past one object can possibly point to another, as evidenced by the example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x[1],y[1];
int test1(int *p)
{
    y[0] = 1;
    if (p==x+1)
        *p = 2; // Note that assignment is to *p and not to x[1] !!!
    return y[0];
}
int test2(int *p)
{
    x[0] = 1;
    if (p==y+1)
        *p = 2; // Note that assignment is to *p and not to y[1] !!!
    return x[0];
}

int (*volatile test1a)(int *p) = test1;
int (*volatile test2a)(int *p) = test2;

int main(void) {
    int q;
    printf("%llX\n",(unsigned long long)y - (unsigned long long)x);
    q = test1a(y);
    printf(">> %d %d\n", y[0], q);
    q = test2a(x);
    printf(">> %d %d\n", x[0], q);
    return 0;
}
```

By my reading of the Standard, valid outputs from this program on the lines marked `>>` would be either `>> 1 1` or `>> 2 2`, but gcc on ideone outputs `>> 2 1` for one of the lines and from what I can tell the code generated by clang would do likewise for the other.

I am well aware that the fact that `p` compares equal to `x[1]` would not imply that the latter expression could be used to access the same object as `*p` (or any object at all, for that matter), but I am aware of nothing in the Standard that would forbid the computation of `x+1` nor comparison between the resulting pointer and `p`.  I am also aware of nothing that would cause such comparison to make `p` unusable for accessing the object whose address it holds.

Is there any plausible reading of any published or draft version of the C Standard under which the above code invokes Undefined Behavior, or under which the returned values from `test1` and `test2` would not be required to match the final values of `y[0]` or `x[0]`, respectively, or are the optimizers in clang and gcc designed to process a dialect that isn't a published or draft version of the Standard?

PS--From the standard draft N1570 6.5.9p6:

> 6   Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the
>       same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function,
>       both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer
>       to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different
>       array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address
>       space.

The Standard does not in any way imply that `x[]` must follow `y[]` nor vice versa, but seems to be explicitly providing for the possibility that a pointer that points just past `x` might be compared to `y` and observed to be equal.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192128/discussion-on-question-by-supercat-is-this-gcc-clang-past-one-pointer-comparison).

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a compiler bug. In most cases, when `p == x+i` evaluates to true for some pointer `p`, array `x`, and integer `i`, it is true that `p` necessarily points to an element in `x` (or the program is executing code with undefined behavior, in which case the compiler is permitted to assume `p` points to an element in `x`). If `p` did point to an element in `x`, it would be true that `*p = 2;` cannot change `y[0]`, and therefore it would be correct for the compiler to generate code that returns the 1 that was recently assigned to `y[0]`. The clues suggest the compiler has attempted an optimization in which it “learns” about `p` through the truth of the comparison.

This deduction fails when `x+i` points to one beyond the end of the array `x`. In C 2018 6.5.9 6, the standard tells us that this comparison may evaluate to true even though `p` points to a different object, unrelated to `x` (but that happens to immediately follow it in memory). The compiler’s deduction ought to be more limited. Given `p+j == x+i`, where `x` is an array of `n` elements, the fact the evaluation is true only implies that `p+k` points to an element of `x` for `j`−`i` ≤ `k` < `n`+`j`−`i`. (In the case in the question, `i`=1, `j`=0, and `k`=0, which fails 0−1 ≤ 0 < 1+0−1.)

(Note that the criterion presented above implies, for the case in the question, that `p-1` points to an element of `x`, since 0−1 ≤ −1 < 0 holds, yet we know `p` points into `y` and is not valid for pointing into `x`. But using it to access `p[-1]` has behavior not defined by the standard, meaning any assumptions are permitted, including that `p[-1]` is an element of `x`. So the compiler is permitted to use the criterion.)

Comment: I would disagree. I think the compiler may assume that x and y are in no guaranteed order. They might end up with padding between them, generated xy or yx by the compiler or sorted differently by the linker script. I believe it's valid for the compiler to assume they are not following each other in memory as no such guarantee is given and optimize the code assuming an order that suits it best.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: It is clear in this case the assumption made by the compiler broke a conforming program. All of the code in the program in the question is defined—the program did not access outside the bounds of an array and did not use a pointer for one object to access an unrelated object. It merely performed a comparison, and the compiler assumed, as a consequence of that comparison, something that was false, and that was false in an observable way and in violation of the behavior required by the C standard.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Furthermore, the compiler may not assume something that is not true and that is detectable and observable per the C standard. Per C 2018 6.3.2.3, the result of converting a pointer to an integer is implementation-defined. Unless the implementation defines a conversion that is largely useless, a program can convert two pointers to integers and ascertain their relationship. Thus, if `y` happens to follow `x` in memory, a program can detect that by this means. Then `x+1 == y` is required to evaluate to true by 6.5.9 7. If it does not, this inconsistency is observable.

Comment: While your first comment may be true. Strictly speaking the compiler would have to ensure x and y are never next to each other in memory. Your second comment though is wrong. There is no conversion to integer happening. `x+1 == y` is a pointer compare. There is no cast to `intptr_t`. And if you cast to `intptr_t` I don't believe you can do any comparisons. As you say converting a pointer to an integer is implementation-defined. My imaginary compiler does that by constructing struct { uint64_t base; uint64_t size; uint64_t offset;} in a 192bit integer, which I believe would be standard conform.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: My second comment does not say there is a conversion to integer happening in the source code in the question (although there is; see `printf("%llX\n",(unsigned long long)y - (unsigned long long)x);`). It says that “a program **can** convert two pointers to integers and ascertain their relationship.” In other words, it is describing how we can write a program that demonstrates the bug in another way. Since the conversion is implementation-defined, if the implementation defines it in a way that allows us to see where objects are located in memory, then we can see the bug.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Additionally, the source code in the question demonstrates the bug as is. The code in the question is conforming C code; it does not access any array out of bounds or perform any operation that is prohibited by the C standard. When the compiler has placed `y` immediately after `x`, then, in `test`, the program sets `y[0]` to 1 and then sets it to `2` in the statement `*p = 2;`. That is a strictly conforming statement; `p` is the address of `y[0]`, taken as the address of `y[0]`, with no funny business. It ought to work, and then `return y[0];` should return 2…

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: It does not, which proves the C implementation is defective.

Comment: I would rather blame the C standard. Given how unpredictable the placement of obejcts in memory is they should have allowed that `x + 1 == y` may be true but not require it. What happens when I write a C compiler with a compacting garbage collector? `x + 1 == y` may be true before compaction but false after because moving objects around in memory would change the order. It couldn't be C standard compliant anymore.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: It is fine to think the C standard should be changed to avoid this issue. Nonetheless, as the C standard stands, the compiler implements it incorrectly. The program has defined behavior. As defined by the C standard, it should print “>> 1 1” or “>> 2 2”. But it does not; it prints “>> 2 1” in some cases. That is a failure of the C implementation to conform to the C standard. The C compiler is responsible for that failure, and a failure to conform to specification is a bug. This is a bug in the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not a compiler bug. Your program has undefined behaviour.

In function `test1` you compare p to x+1, but p==y so the pointers are totally unrelated, which gives you undefined behaviour. And compilers are not required to warn for that. It is impossible to detect in this case.

So the comparisons to p in both functions may or may not evaluate to true, but it is unpredictable what will happen, depending on the memory layout.

Compiler bugs are rare, if you think you found one, think again and look for undefined behaviour.

Comment: N1570 6.5.9p6: "Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, *or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space*."  Why should the last clause not be applicable here?  The authors of clang and gcc might view that text as...

Comment: ...a defect in the Standard, since it would be incompatible with the abstraction model they use, but I can't see any way to interpret that text as having any meaningful effect if it wouldn't define the behavior of this program in the scenario that `x` happens to immediately follow `y` or vice versa.

Comment: To be fair, that corner case would rarely be relevant in most scenarios where the language is used (though it could be important in cases where C code imports symbols the linker created to mark the start and end of a memory region whose size is computed at link time).  On the other hand, I regard as hypocritical the attitude that the maintainers of clang and gcc regard as gospel cases where the Standard characterizes as UB constructs that should be useful, but ignore the Standard in cases where it explicitly defines the behavior of constructs they don't want to support.

Comment: Some useful things are intentionally left undefined by the standard as they would depend on a particular hardware model. And the standard only specifies an abstract machine. But compilers are free to implement that as they see fit i.e. in a useful way or the way with the least overhead.

Comment: Many useful things are deliberately left undefined by the Standard, on the assumption that implementations whose customers would find them useful would define them whether or not they were required by the Standard.  On the other hand, given the text I quoted above, I would not regard this scenario as one of them.  In what way does the scenario that causes trouble here not *precisely* match one of the scenarios where the Standard explicitly prescribes the behavior as "the pointers compare equal"?